# App Bar Icon XAML WP8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I wish to use [**this icon**](http://www.geekchamp.com/icon-explorer/transport-icons/icon?code=1F698) for my **app bar button** on a windows phone app.

I can do it using the **.png** files. **But how to use it in XAML for Windows Phone.**

I am looking for a way to do it like that in Windows 8. ie- using it with **Content Tag and using a Font to draw it.**

Comment: Don't understand, what's the problem. Doesn't reference to downloaded picture in resources work?

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it like that in Windows 8. ie- using it as Content Tag and using a Font to draw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the current Windows Phone SDK.

The `ApplicationBarIconButton` only support rendered images.

Answer (score 3):

Download and add the image to the project.

```
/Assets/1F698-Car.48.png
```

In **Xaml**:

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

---

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/1F698-Car.48.png"
                                        Text="Car" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

[image]

Comment: I said in the question that it was possible using the .png file. I am looking for a way to do it like that in Windows 8. ie- using it as Content and using a Font to draw it.